# Authorizing USB debugging on a dead touchscreen

Tags: android, adb, usb-otg, google-pixel

I've got a Google Pixel 6 that fell face down and has a dead screen - both image and touch inputs do not work. I'm trying to access and move important files from the phone to a laptop and this is where I'm running into an issue.

Though I had activated USB debugging, there is currently an 'allow usb debugging' prompt to authorize the laptop device. This prevents me from not just file transfer, but also from using scrcpy to view the screen.

Is there any way to either view the screen or authorize my device?

I know the phone isn't dead because it still vibrates from calls and messages. I've attempted to use scrcpy's otg, but haven't been able to make any progress as I'm navigating completely blindly. I'd need to input the PIN, find the correct notification for the usb debug authorization and then hit allow, all while blind and with almost no feedback aside from some light vibrations. I doubt I'll be able to do that and I've ran out of ideas.

Comment: This question is better suited for e.g. superuser stack exchange. If you have a USB-C to HDMI, you can use the screen share feature with a USB mouse. Just checked with my Note 10+.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd need to input the PIN, find the correct notification for the usb debug authorization and then hit allow

If USB debugging is already enabled but not authorized:

1. plug your device over USB
2. run `scrcpy --otg`
3. type your PIN and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to validate the USB debugging popup
5. USB debugging should now be authorized (scrcpy OTG should close due to USB reconfiguration)
6. run `scrcpy` normally (with `scrcpy --turn-screen-off` to avoid performance issues with a broken screen due to vsync)